# What does this Yii error #8192 mean?

Tags: php, heroku, yii2

I get this error on Heroku for a Yii2 app. I searched the source code and can't even find error 8192.

> Error (#8192)
>   An internal server error occurred.

Other pages work, but just this one page doesn't work. There is no error message in `heroku logs`. There is no `runtime/logs/app.log` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because I was accessing a non-static class method statically. It worked in development. I had to turn on debugging in production (which was a big hassle by itself) to find out.

Comment: I have the same problem. please explain more about it

Comment: `Class::function()` instead of `classInstance->function()`

Comment: I have a line `$commentCount=PostController::actionGetCommentCount($model->‌​id)` that it works correctly, but in host does not work. how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is switch on debugging on your deployed server.  This was an issue for me as Heroku gave me problems when I did not switch off debugging.  However, I managed to switch it on in YII 2 by going into the web/index.php and setting the debug options as follows:

```
 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
 defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'production');
```

When I put the environment to production Heroku seemed to work.  However, I did a lot of other stuff before getting to this point such as updating with composer and making sure all the required files are present.  After doing this I could locate the function that was being called statically.  Hope it helps!