# #8192 internal error in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I made this project on **localhost** in xampp with yii2. the project **works** correctly in localhost but after upload it to host, I got bellow error:

```
errror #8192
 Internal server error.
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
```

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290467/what-does-this-yii-error-8192-mean) does't helped me.

I really need help to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this Yii error #8192 mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290467/what-does-this-yii-error-8192-mean)

Comment: @Bizley I could not understand the answer on that page

Comment: The answer means that you probably have got method defined like this `public function method()` and you try to call it like `Object::method()` which is not allowed.

Comment: @Bizley so how do I have to call it?

Comment: For example like this: `(new Object)->method()`

Comment: @Bizley I don't have something like this

Comment: This is **just example**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142599/discussion-between-mohammad-aghayari-and-bizley).

Comment: Please run the requirements.php file which is resides outside of web directory in yii2-basic. From that file you will come to know all requirements are satisfy your server or not also give writable permission for runtime and web/assets directory and give a try please.

Comment: I find the line of problem. I've used `$commentCount=PostController::actionGetCommentCount($model->id)`.
how could I use this code to work correctly?